# What is the biblical basis for NOT believing that everyone has a fair chance to be saved?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, free-will, predestination, justice

In my previous question [If everyone has a fair chance to be saved, then how is this reconciled with Romans 10:11-17 & John 6:44?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89756/50422), I laid out two conditions for scoping purposes:

> This question is scoped to Christians who believe that:
>
> - *humans have [libertarian free will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarianism_(metaphysics))* (or
>   at least are given temporarily some form of genuine freedom of the
>   will through divine grace in specific circumstances)
> - *everyone has a fair chance to be saved at least once in their life* (i.e. no one is born in conditions where salvation is theoretically
>   impossible, or, alternatively, everyone is given enough grace to have
>   the opportunity to freely choose salvation at least once before
>   judgement)

Interestingly, a user posted the following dissident comment in the comment section (emphasis mine):

> **There is no element of chance attached to God's salvation**. It's not a case of, God has taken nine steps to enable it, but the human must choose to take the final, tenth step. Yet that's what most people effectively think, and that's how they act. God will ensure all who are to be saved will hear the gospel and understand it. **You can't get fairer that that, when nothing has been left to chance!** Therefore, I'm not answering because not only am I not scoped, **the question is fundamentally flawed**.

Assuming that the thoughts shared by this user represent to different extents the soteriological position of many Christians, I ask:

What is the biblical basis for **NOT** believing that everyone has a fair chance to be saved?

Comment: You misinterpret Anne's comment (because she didn't disclose her theological assumption, which is classic Calvinist Reformed like Dr. James White, implying double predestination, but if understood properly STILL includes consideration of free will).  What she most likely mean is the orchestration of providence which is complete (nothing left to chance) but which include pseudo-libertarian free will **for every one**.  This is mainly to insulate the righteous so their premature death / suffering can at the end be for something good.  The opposite is Open Theism.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple You are in danger of somewhat misrepresenting me too, because what I mean is that considering human free will first, then subjecting our theological conclusions to that next, is to put the cart before the horse; thus getting nowhere. God's statements on our hopeless condition must be accepted first, then we can see whether any free will (as we suppose it) comes into that dire picture. Most people try to shoehorn it in (wishing to have some control, or say, in the matter). So, please don't try connecting me to 'double predestination' or Dr. White. I'm connected to God's word.

Comment: @Spirit Realm Investigator -You may assume what you like, but for as long as you keep using in your questions the phrase, “a fair chance to be saved” (the way you use it), I will not answer, because that is the fundamental flaw in all such questions. I have briefly enlarged on that in my comment to Grateful Disciple, above.

Comment: @Anne - would you be so kind as to post an answer?

Comment: Thank you for the direct invitation, but my comment to your previous Q (which you quoted) and my comment to Grateful Disciple, above, is all that I'm going to say on the matter here.

Comment: @Anne - well, at least I tried ...

Comment: Yes, you're very trying (! Smiles!)

Comment: @Anne Thank you for correcting me.  In the first place, I shouldn't have attempted to clarify (for SpiritRealmInvestigator's benefit) what I think is the background assumption of your comment.  Instead I should have waited for you to clarify yourself.  I'm glad you corrected me.  In the future I will refrain from doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Romans chapters 1, 2, and half way through three takes the reader through a series of self-examinations.

> the invisible things of him from the creation of the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse ...

> ... God also gave them up to uncleanness through the lusts of their own hearts, to dishonour their own bodies between themselves ...

> ... God gave them up unto vile affections ...

> ... they did not like to retain God in their knowledge,  ...

And the conclusion is :

> ... Therefore thou art inexcusable, O man ...

> ... There is none righteous, no, not one ...

> ... There is none that understandeth, there is none that seeketh after God ...

> ... They are all gone out of the way, they are together become unprofitable; there is none that doeth good, no, not one.

One either argues (with the Apostle Paul) as to this assessment of the children of Adam. or one bows, humbles oneself admits one's own sin and accepts the righteous judgment of God - *against oneself.*

Each is judged according to their own circumstances, their own person.

And this passage brings all under condemnation.

---

Everyone has *already had* every opportunity.

Everyone *has already been given* all that could be given.

And every one, every single one, went astray and did evil.

All have sinned and failed of the glory of God ('fallen short' is a bad translation - it is an utter failure).

To these, these abject failures, these sinful persons, comes the gospel of the grace of God.

And still it is rejected, by all but those whom God, himself, calls.

*For salvation is of the Lord.*

---

Therefore there is no 'chance' attached to salvation.

As the user has commented, there is no support for believing that *anyone* has a 'chance' to be saved.

If we only had a 'chance' - none of us would be saved.

It is *all of God*. Every part is of God, from before the foundation of the world being chosen in Christ ; to receiving the preached gospel (such beautiful feet have they who preach such a gospel !) ; to being justified (by God himself) ; to being sanctified by the Holy Spirit ; to being glorified in eternal glory.

Nothing, *but nothing* is left to 'chance', or the withered hand of humanity's supposed 'free will'.

Comment: So free will doesn't exist? Humans are automatons deterministically predestined to either salvation or damnation?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I recommend the study of the first three chapters of Romans, as I stated above. There is none righteous. No, not one. Romans 7 is clear about the so-called 'ability' of humanity to do good. I am surprised at your reaction. _It is not of him that willeth_. It never is. Humanity (in Adam) has utterly failed. Being offered a 'chance' is not effective. Humanity is too lost, too far fallen. I know this, not from the page but from bitter, bitter experience of the worthlessness of all my own religion. _Salvation is of the Lord_. Amen.

Comment: Nigel, what are your thoughts on this question: [What is the biblical basis for free will?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54588/50422)

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I am not aware that scripture ever mentions the words 'free will'. Or teaches the concept.

Comment: I prefer to say we have *real* wills. We make true choices that are our own. But we are afflicted by sin and circumstance.

Comment: @curiousdannii - are you a determinist?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I don't know what you mean by that. But I am Reformed, and believe that God is sovereign.

Comment: @curiousdannii - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism